# web2py routes.py not working as shown in book

Tags: python, routes, web2py

I am attempting to implement a URL routing scheme in a web2py application and am not getting anywhere fast. I have tried on linux and Windows to implement the example found [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04?search=routes_in#Pattern-based-system).  I have the following (which is just a renaming of the example given) in the web2py directory, not the application directory:

```
routes_in = (...,('/report', '/reporter/reporter/index'),)
routes_out = (...,('/reporter/reporter/index', '/report),)
```

Is there something that I am missing? This seems like it should be pretty basic. I am running web2py v 2.5.1 and have tried on a Windows 7 and Ubuntu install.

**Edit:** There are other routes defined in routes_in and routes_out, which are the routes provided as an example.

Comment: Did you reload routes (via the button in the admin app) or restart the server?

Comment: Yes. I did both multiple times and I was able to get the routes to fail when I put an error into the routing patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a comma. Try this:

```
routes_in = (('/report', '/reporter/reporter/index'),)
routes_out = (('/reporter/reporter/index', '/report'),)
```

Comment: I apologize, I should have added that this was the last tuple in the tuple and that there was a comma after it. See edit.

Comment: Your answer led me to thinking that perhaps there may be something wrong with all the routes that precede my custom route. I deleted that the routes work fine. It would appear that the routes provided as an example were causing my routes to not be read. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

One suggestion : if you have a lot of "routes_in" tuples you can simplify routes_out to avoid typo issues...

For example :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
routes_in = (
  (r'/', r'/myApp/pages/'),
  (r'/images', r'/myApp/images/images'),
  (r'/contact', r'/myApp/default/contact_form'),
  (r'/robots.txt', r'/myApp/static/robots.txt'),
  #A lot of stuff here...
)
routes_out = [(x, y) for (y, x) in routes_in]
```

Comment: Even more, if you want some rules in `routes_in` but not in `routes_out` you can put them at the end of `routes_in`. Let's imagine that you don't want the last two rules, you can assign to `routes_out` the next: `[(x, y) for (y, x) in routes_in[:-2]]`